# Christmas Carol Sentence - use of "trial"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> I'm sorry with all my heart to find you so resolute... **But I have made the trial in homage to Christmas**, and I'll keep my Christmas humor to the last.

This was from the chapter *Marley's Ghost* by Charles Dickens. I searched that homage means "respect", but what does the phrase "But I have made the trial in homage to Christmas" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Scrooge's nephew speaking (not Marley's ghost), after he has *tried* to get his Uncle to recognise Christmas. "Made the trial" is a flowery way of saying "tried" or "made the attempt" - it is not an expression I have ever heard anybody use, and I don't think it would be understood in speech today.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Oh, I thought the name of the chapter was called Marley's Ghost.

Comment: You're right that the Chapter is called _Marley's Ghost_. I would not usually recognise any of the chapter names in any book I had read, so the only meaning of "from Marley's Ghost" I could find was "spoken by (the character) Marley's Ghost". If you're going to refer to chapters of books, you need to say 'from the chapter "Marley's Ghost"' or something similar.